# Insert Javascript code in Popup.FramedCloud?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I would like to have a live stream from a web camera in a Popup.FramedCloud.
All I need to do is to insert this code in the HTML code parameter for popup:

```
<script src="http://www.live-events.ro/cam-acces-privat-delay.js.php?id=13" 
type="text/javascript">
```

From my tests this is not working.  Tell me if you tried this with success.

The script is correct, [you can see it in action here](http://www.trafficguide.ro/camere-live/bucuresti-obor).

I tried something more simple like "eval('a=1;alert(a)')" but with no success. I see the code in Firebug, but alert window does not appear.

The alternative I think of is to use other object for the popup, an Ext JS object maybe or some kind of reach tooltip library.

Answer (score 1):

if you want set your html, you can use setContentHTML for OpenLayers. I don’t know it works for you or not, but you can check out it [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup-js.html#OpenLayers.Popup.setContentHTML).

```
setContentHTML:function(    contentHTML )
Allows the user to set the HTML content of the popup.

Parameters
contentHTML {String} HTML for the div.
```

if it is not work, try to use iframe into popup.

Answer (score 0):

Iframe works into popup, but is not a clean solution because I need to transport some variables to the JS script inside de iframe.

I can't use setContentHTML() function because I am using FeaturePopup library to show cluster popups. [I asked Jorix for help to inject JS code](https://github.com/jorix/OL-FeaturePopups/issues/6). He made the library and already helped me very much with some related problems.